# Error sending HTTP request. (Not able to connect to openAM from mule HTTPS)

Tags: ssl, https, mule

I am not able to access, token API from openAM over HTTPS from mule. Using Postman I am able to access the token API, but from mule proxy, it is not working.

I got below error:

```
Message : Error sending HTTP request. Element : null

Exception stack is: Error sending HTTP request.   
(org.mule.api.MessagingException) 
sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(null:-1) 
sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(null:-1)
sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(null:-1)
sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(null:-1)
sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(null:-1)
sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(null:-1)
sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(null:-1)
sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(null:-1)
sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(null:-1)
sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(null:-1)
sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(null:-1)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(null:-2)
sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(null:-1)
org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLUtils.executeDelegatedTask(SSLUtils.java:274)
org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLBaseFilter.java:699)
org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLFilter.java:332)
org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLBaseFilter.java:613)
org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.handleRead(SSLBaseFilter.java:318)
com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.SwitchingSSLFilter.handleRead(SwitchingSSLFilter.java:74)
org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.run0(FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.java:134)
org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.access$100(FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.java:31)
org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.java:157)
(3 more...)
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: This question is very vague. You will need to add more details. What does your HTTPS configuration file look like?

Comment: Hi Mooz Thanks for reply

Comment: I have SOLVED ISSUE by adding below code                                               <tls:context name="test" >
       <tls:trust-store insecure="true"/>
   </tls:context>

Comment: you should write that in an answer so that others who have the problem will know the solution too.

Comment: Thanks Mooz posted in anser

Answer (score 0):

I have SOLVED ISSUE by adding below code 
<tls:context name="test" > <tls:trust-store insecure="true"/> </tls:context>

Comment: We shouldnot use this `insecure="true"` until we have got valid reason to do so.